# Why 'args cannot be read at compile time'

Tags: d

I am trying to use `mixin` in following code:

```
import std.stdio; 
import std.file;

void main(string[] args){
    if (args.length != 2)   {
        writeln("usage: ./app < number expression >");
        return;
    }
    else    {
        // following statements work ok: 
        writeln(args); 
        writeln(args.length); 
        writeln(args[1]); 

        // following 2 statements do not work; same error:   
        //mixin("writeln("~args[1]~");"); //    Error: variable args cannot be read at compile time
        writeln(mixin(args[1]));  //        Error: variable args cannot be read at compile time
    }
}
```

But I am getting following error:

```
$ rdmd soq_mycalc.d
soq_mycalc.d(17): Error: variable args cannot be read at compile time
Failed: ["/usr/bin/dmd", "-v", "-o-", "soq_mycalc.d", "-I."]
```

Where is the problem and how can it be corrected?

Edit: I want to call this program with argument: "2+2" and want the program to calculate it.

Following also does not work:

```
char[] mainarg = args[1].dup;
writeln(mixin(mainarg));  // Error: variable args cannot be read at compile time
```

Comment: How can it be compile time? `args` are program arguments, they change after you compile your program and can be different on each run.

Comment: Then what is meaning of this error?

Comment: Just what is says - `Error: variable args cannot be read at compile time`. This is the meaning. `mixin` is used to compile strings into executable D code. But it can be done only with strings that can be read at compile time. `args` can't be read at compile time, it is set after compilation. `how can it be corrected?` - you need to write your own whole code to compile the "number expression" you want. There is no magic "mixin" command. Or you can kind-of invoke the D compiler, using some `std.system()` call.

Comment: Ok. What is the solution. I want to call this program with arguments such as "2+2" and want it to calculate it. Pl see edit in my question above.

Comment: Read a character. Convert string `2` into number. Read a character. It's a `+` you will need to add it. Read a character. Convert character `2` into a number. Calculate result. Print the result.

Comment: What is the equivalent of `eval` command in D? The problem with reading characters as separate arguments is that `*` is converted by bash to all directories in system.

Comment: There is none. There is no equivalent of eval. D is not a scripting language. It is a compiled language. There is a compiler. To do `eval`, you need to implement the whole D compiler. Start with a good D tutorial. The problem with globulation `*` in shells is about escaping or quoting not "reading". Read [quotes](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes).

Comment: Also '(' and ')' are not accepted on command line.

Comment: There is an example on the D home page of an RPN calculator. It's a simple example, but shows how to accomplish what your are trying to do. On dlang.org, there is a code examples box at the top-right. From the drop-down select "Tiny RPN Calculator". It takes expressions like "2 3 + 10 *" on the command line [translates to (2+3)*10]. The code is a little daunting if you are new to D, but essentially, its a standalone calculator that calculates expressions given on the command line. As mentioned by others, D doesn't have an "eval" function that evaluates an arbitrary D expression.

Comment: The RPN calculator code is very interesting.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand well, what you are trying to achieve is some form of expression evaluation (which involves parsing an expression grammar). BASH for an example has `eval()` that can take arbitrary expression as string, and return a value (if the expression is valid).

D standard library does not have such function as far as I know.

For a simple solution I would use [Pegged](https://github.com/PhilippeSigaud/Pegged) ([Reference](http://bford.info/pub/lang/peg)). [DLang Tour's Pegged page](https://tour.dlang.org/tour/en/dub/pegged) is a good starting point so I recommend you start from there.

Comment: Thanks for a very interesting and useful package on parsing.